# What do I put on the html page so that the browser knows to access it through ssl?

Tags: html, ssl

I have a certificate installed on my web server.  If I just want one page to be accessed through ssl, what do I need to mark up on the page, or is another setting somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the only reliable way is to link to it using an `https://` URL only. Ideally, you should make sure that your users expect HTTPS to be used, and that they will check that it's used properly (i.e. they won't ignore browser warnings).

Anything that's enforced on the server after a plain HTTP request is potentially vulnerable to MITM attacks. This include redirect methods via `mod_rewrite`, PHP headers (`Location` headers), JavaScript (extracting `window.location`), ..., and of course, the initial delivery of the `https://` link itself, if it's obtained from a page served over plain HTTP. Even a denial of access due to something like `SSLRequireSSL` is only effective after a plain HTTP request has been received.

It's not a bad idea to use these redirection techniques, if only to get your users used to the fact they're using HTTPS (they may notice something odd if on another occasion they're not, which would possibly indicate a MITM attack), and they should at least protect them against passive eavesdropping attacks.

More generally, even if you are serving `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` with the same host name (and possibly the same server software), they are technically two distinct hosts (e.g. virtual hosts in the Apache Httpd terminology) and resources hosted on one need not be hosted on the other. Simply don't server the pages you only want via HTTPS on your plain HTTP host. I'd also suggest *not* to use redirects (at least during the development phase), so that it breaks when you're not linking to those pages using HTTPS: this will help detect potential mixed-content problems. The automatic redirects are mainly useful for users who type in the address directly into their browsers.

You could consider getting your site in the pre-loaded [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) lists (or at least use HSTS, which would make the browser remember to use HTTPS only after it has worked at least once), but this will apply to the entire host.

You can find more details in these answers, on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/22859/2435) and on [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628).

Comment: You don't consider SSLRequireSSL reliable?

Comment: @EJP, it's not that I don't consider it reliable, it works, but it can only be enforced by the server, once it receives a request. If the browser (and user) doesn't know it should make the request with HTTPS, then a MITM could be making that connection with HTTPS (coming from the browser with plain HTTP). In addition `SSLRequireSSL` doesn't tell the browser to access the page with HTTPS (like redirects would), it just denies access if it's not the case. Ultimately, I still think the only way to make sure the browser uses HTTPS is to use an `https://` link to that page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't understand about the MITM part, can you expand on that? Also I would have expected SSLRequireSSL to send a redirect. Doesn't it do that? (Must say here that my own mechanism is an HTTPS: action link on the login form, which works perfectly for me.)

Comment: @EJP, say the user/browser doesn't know that the page is to be requested with HTTPS, it makes the request using plain HTTP, a MITM could intercept that request, stop it, make the request using HTTPS itself and respond to the user (possibly altered) with plain HTTP. It's the same principle as verifying the cert and host name, it's ultimately up to the user/browser to check. AFAIR, [`SSLRequireSSL`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) just returns a 403 status if SSL/TLS isn't used ("*When this directive is present all requests are denied which are not using SSL.*").

Comment: I didn't realize that the page would be accessible with both protocols out of the box.  I did have to complete the installation with a 3rd party hosting service with a validation process.  From what Bruno is saying about MITM exploits I can see how supposedly secure sessions can be quite vulnerable, as it looks like the majority of browsers out there aren't set up with HSTS.

Comment: @Jean-Paul, HTTPS connections are normally secure, if the user expects them to be there. It's like real-life situations: if you deposit cash in your bank, it's up to you to make sure it's indeed in your bank you've walked in. Your bank can at best educate your, but it can't do anything if you don't expect yourself to meet a bank employee and give your cash to any random individual instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example how to do it in PHP

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
   header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit;
}
```

Here how to do it in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.protocol != 'https:') {
        window.location.href = 'https://' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    }
</script>
```

To use only HTML, you can do:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.yoursite.com" />
```

I believe you could also do it directly in Apache config.

Comment: Hey, this is PHP code.  The question is what you put on an **html** page.

Comment: True, I added the solution using Javascript and HTML only.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is configured properly all you need to do it to link to that page using https://.

to check and make sure no access the page without https, you can use php to find the current exact URL and check and see if its https, if its not, do a simple redirect to https://[URL]

Comment: One option is to use PHP, but there are many other options as well.  If Apache is being used then mod_rewrite is another option (also not the only way)

Answer (score 0):

If the server is configured properly there is nothing you need to put on the page *or* on links to it. Just define a Location block in the Apache configuration for the page with an SSLRequireSSL directive.